# A XML Schema for mysqldump XML

Tags: xml, xsd, mysql, dtd, relaxng

Does there exist a Schema (DTD, XML Schema or RELAX NG) for the XML output produced by

```
mysqldump --xml -u
```

if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything official, but you may be able to leverage the mysqldump XSDs that are parts of the [**Dragonfly CMS**](https://code.google.com/p/dragonfly-cms/source/browse/includes/poodle/sql/xml/mysqldump.xsd) or the [**XSD Sandbox**](https://github.com/lindenb/xsd-sandbox/blob/master/schemas/mysql/mysqldump.xsd) projects.